# Understanding Pivot Tables in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sum, pivot, mean

I am trying to display a tabular pivot table for all combinations of 2 attributes. We'll name them `"STORE_STATE"` and `"PRODUCT_CATEGORY_CODE"`. For each combo, I want to be able to show the `SUM` and `MEAN` for each of the columns. I have three different columns: we'll say they are `"PRICE, QUANTITY` and `TOTAL_PAID_FOR_ITEM`".

For now, I have been given a template of:

```
yearlyIncome = df.pivot_table(values = ["YearlyIncome"], index=["Gender", "MaritalStatus", "BikeBuyer"], aggfunc=np.mean) print(yearlyIncome)
```

This was part of a different sheet, but if I were to do it with the attributes that I have, I'm not so sure where I should start if I only have this to base it off of.

I want to be able to show the `SUM` and `MEAN` for each of the columns.

Comment: Please show an example of your input data and the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
index_cols = ['STORE_STATE', 'PRODUCT_CATEGORY_CODE']
cols = ['PRICE', 'QUANTITY', 'TOTAL_PAID_FOR_ITEM']
pqt = df.pivot_table(index=index_cols, values=cols, aggfunc=(np.sum, np.mean))
pqt.head()
```